# WebLogic ClassCastException during RMI

Tags: weblogic, rmi, downcast

So I setup two remote WebLogic applications to use RMI to communicate with each other.

The LocalServiceAPI.java file is located in the same package in the client & the host.

The same code works on my local machine on a test server, but does not on my company's unix server.

Both server versions are 12.1.3.0.0

The oddest thing: the narrow is successful, but the cast throws the classCastException.

```
    Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://" + address + ":" + port);

    Object obj = PortableRemoteObject.narrow(new InitialContext(env).lookup("LocalServiceAPI"), LocalServiceAPI.class);
    return (LocalServiceAPI) obj;
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cleargoals.service.LocalServiceAPIImpl_12130_WLStub cannot be cast to com.cleargoals.service.LocalServiceAPI
```

Comment: This sounds quite a bit like these questions, maybe one of them will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393824/remote-interface-cannot-be-cast-to-ejb-container   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816996/class-cast-exception-in-narrow-a-jndi-reffrence-in-ejb

Answer (score 0):

Since your server version is 12.1.3. So I assume it is EJB3 compliant server. For EJb3, context.lookup method call assumes parameter passed is an global JDNI name of remote class...So ensure u r passing global JNDI name of remote class in lookup call...Read [link](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#What_is_the_syntax_for_portable_global_) if you are not sure what is meant by global word in JNDI name...Secondly, since EJB2, you are not required to use PortableRemoteObject.narrow method, the lookup call itself does the work for you...its explanation is also in same link.